# When use BaumWelchLearner in Java, is there a limitation of the sequences' length (These sequences are used to train the hmm model)

Tags: java, nlp, hidden-markov-models

Thank you in advance!

I used BaumWelchLeaner() in java like this:

`BaumWelchLearner bwl = new BaumWelchLearner();
 hmm = bwl.learn(hmm, seqs);`

where "seqs" are my preprocessed training data.

However, if the sequence in "seqs" has a length more than 107, even though the statistics in "pi","statesTostates" and "statesToObser" matrix are OK, all the test data will be predicted to have a hidden sequence like this:

"0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0".

But if I control all the sequences' length to be less than 107, the result of prediction will be OK. 
According to jahmm.learn.BaumWelchLearner, there only say the length should >= 2. So I don't know how to solve my problem.